# Authentication error while trying to connect to MongoDB using Hibernate OGM : OGM001213: MongoDB authentication failed with username

Tags: java, hibernate, mongodb, jpa, hibernate-ogm

I am trying to connect to MongoDB using Hibernate OGM. My persistance.xml is as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="primary">
<provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="admindb"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="27017"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="admin"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="welcome"/>
</properties>
```

I get the following error when I try to run the associated code:

```
2015-05-04 16:26:32 DEBUG HibernatePersistenceProvider:82 - Unable to build entity manager factory
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000071: Unable to start datatore provider
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.start(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.startService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectInitiator.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectInitiator.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator$OgmDialectFactory.(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmJdbcServicesInitiator$OgmJdbcServicesImpl.configure(OgmJdbcServicesInitiator.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.test.nosql.Test.main(Test.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM001213: MongoDB authentication failed with username [admin]
```

I'm using the following dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have checked the MongoDB authentication through commandline and I was able to login. But for some reason Hibernate OGM is not being allowed to authenticate. Please help.

Comment: Did you set credentials manually and/or turn on authentication when starting the database server?  By default mongodb does not need to authenticate

Comment: I did add some users manually and I am trying to use them for hibernate OGM.

Comment: Can you test it with the latest Hibernate OGM release, 4.2.0? There have been several fixes around authentication against MongoDB since 4.1.